# Can i use two webgrids in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

I followed this link http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC 
This is good for single webgrid, but if i create two webgrids in same page with different number of columns i am getting errors how to solve this issue

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5, 
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow",ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridContent");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 

<div id="gridContent">
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            grid.Column("Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)),
            grid.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description")
     )) 
</div>

     @{
    var gridsecond = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 5,
    selectionFieldName: "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "secondgridContent");
        grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);} 

<div id="secondgridContent">
    @gridsecond.GetHtml(tableStyle: "webGrid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
            selectedRowStyle: "select",
            columns: gridsecond.Columns(
            gridsecond.Column("Id", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Id)),
            gridsecond.Column("Name", format: (item) => item.GetSelectLink(item.Name)),
            gridsecond.Column("Description", "Description", style: "description"),
            gridsecond.Column("Quantity", "Quantity")
     )) 
</div>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: column 'Quantity' doesnot exists for first grid

Comment: Try changing grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious) in the second grid to **gridsecond**.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious)

Comment: @ Praveen Paulose no luck at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple WebGrids on the same page, you need to provide each with a unique `FieldNamePrefix` and `PageFieldName` value. You can do that via its constructor:

```
var grid1 = new WebGrid(Model1, fieldNamePrefix: "g1", pageFieldName: "p1");
var grid2 = new WebGrid(Model2, fieldNamePrefix: "g2", pageFieldName: "p2");
```

Comment: I googled ,several times but you are the only one, a champion work